# Can this function return DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason parsing this XML string...I'm getting this error at  `dom.async = false;`
...in theory this should be possible?

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  function parseXml(xml) {
    var dom = null;
    if (window.DOMParser) {
      try { 
         dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml"); 
      } 
      catch (e) { dom = null; }
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
         dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
         dom.async = false;
         if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) // parse error ..
            window.alert(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText);
      } 
      catch (e) { dom = null; }
   }
   else
      alert("oops");
   return dom;
}
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: In IE 11 the break-point stopped and this line of code....no reason why or anything. I've stepped over the line of code and finished processing my element....and my page rendered like it supposed to be.

Comment: Why don't you just use `jQuery.parseXML`? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

Comment: Actually I'm trying to convert my xml element to Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) IE11 Cannot be detected by **window.ActiveXObject**.